A large maze with locked doors and keys
Note: This is my second post, so if the answer to this question is extremely complicated, I apologize in advance.
We are fairly familiar with the standard "How many ways are there to get from the bottom left vertex to the top right vertex in a grid if we can only move up and right", where pictured is an m x n grid.
The answer to this is simply $\binom{m+n}{n} = \binom{m+n}{m}$.
We can imagine this as a rectangular maze where the player wants to travel from the start (located at the bottom left corner) to the finish (at the top right corner) in $m+n$ moves.
We are also somewhat familiar with the scenario if some paths cannot be traveled. This is similar to placing a locked door where there should be a path. We will label these "doors" as black dots, and you cannot travel through them.
To solve this, we could consider smaller "sub-mazes" of completely travel-able paths, and multiply all cases together.
My idea is: What if we added keys (red dots) at certain points in this maze? When you make it to a red dot, you gain a key. These keys can unlock any door but once used cannot be used again. One example is shown in the diagram below.
Is there still a simple way to derive the number of ways to get from the start to the finish if we can only travel up and right, or not? I am estimating a lot of casework for this problem, but I could be wrong.
EDIT: I hope the wording of the problem makes sense, if not could someone please help make it more understandable?
Second edit: Note that you can finish the maze with leftover keys!

-problem created by me!-

The basic idea is to consider this as counting paths from one vertex to another in a directed graph, where the vertices represent "states" and the arcs (directed edges) go from each state to the possible next states.  In your variant, the state must specify both the position in your grid and the number of keys.  The basic recurrence equation is then
$$N(s, t) = \sum_{s'} N(s',t)$$
where $N(s,t)$ is the number of paths from state $s$ to state $t$, and the sum is over all states $s'$ that can be reached in one step from state $s$.

A great answer to an otherwise seemingly complicated problem! As a bonus, could you also solve the example I gave with this recurrence?
